# Receive REPORT_DATA_SOURCE not found even though it exists

Tags: jasper-reports

I try to use the default **REPORT_DATA_SOURCE** parameter in *iReport* to pass the data from a data source to my sub report to be further passed down to another sub report within the sub report. I am able to see **REPORT_DATA_SOURCE** as a parameter in the list of parameters in the main report but when I set the connection type in the sub report and try to set the data source expression to the following: *`new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{REPORT_DATA_SOURC‌​E})`*, I get a ***JRValidationException*** saying parameter is not found.

Any idea why it is doing that, when this is a built in parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to do

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{REPORT_DATA_SOURC‌​E})
```

at all. You should be able to simply set the Data Source Expression to

```
$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}
```

$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} is an instance of JRDataSource which is the interface that all the different types of Data Sources JasperReports defines implements. At the actual report level it does not matter which specific implementation of JRDataSource it is.

Also not that in your code you where actually trying to pass a JRDataSource instance to the constructor of JRBeanCollectionDataSource to create a new instance. No need to do that either.

Comment: Thanks jschoen and Vyccus. REPORT_DATA_SOURCE seems to work, in that there are no exceptions thrown during compilation. My data source that i am passing contains two further lists that are to be passed down to two different sub sub reports via a sub report. The sub sub report references fields that were being set as properties to a java bean. Is this the correct way of passing data ?? The reason i ask is that nothing gets printed even though the report runs fine and to just do a test, i am trying to print a static label on the column header and even that is not printed.